# How to orthogonalize a set of vectors in GNU Octave?

Tags: octave, linear-algebra

Mathematica has a function [Orthogonalization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/LinearAlgebra/Orthogonalization.html), which, when given a set of vectors, orthogonalizes them.

Is some similar built in routine available in GNU Octave?

Of course, I can set up for loops to orthogonalize a set of vectors using Gram-Schmidt method, but I was looking for a built in routine.

Comment: in https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Basic-Matrix-Functions.html#Basic-Matrix-Functions there is mention of orth() which finds an orthogonal basis of the range space of a matrix. If the columns of the matrix are your given vectors, a basis for the range space is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can try `qr` to orthogonalize a set of vectors.

Given a set of vectors

```
v1 = [3,4,2];
v2 = [2,5,2];
v3 = [1,2,6];
```

we bind all vectors by columns to form a matrix `A`, and then perform `qr`, e.g.,

```
A = [v1;v2;v3]';
[Q,R] = qr(A);
```

then we will see

```
Q =

  -0.557086   0.787070  -0.264906
  -0.742781  -0.614899  -0.264906
  -0.371391   0.049192   0.927173

R =

  -5.38516  -5.57086  -4.27099
   0.00000  -1.40197  -0.14758
   0.00000   0.00000   4.76832
```

where the columns in `Q` are the orthogonal vectors.